# Subtract two dataframes in Spark structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a simple program with Spark structured streaming as follows. I need to find the different between two dataframes **d1** and **d2**. However, I got following exeption:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Except on a streaming DataFrame/Dataset on the right is not supported;;

```
val lines = spark.readStream.format("socket")
   .option("host", "localhost").option("port", 9999).load()

val dataset = lines.as[String].map(line => {
  val arr = line.split(",")
  (arr(0), arr(1), arr(2))
})

val d1 = dataset.map(row => row._1)
val d2 = dataset.map(row => row._2)
val res = d1.except(d2)

val query = res.writeStream
  .outputMode("update")
  .format("console")
  .start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Does anyone know any other ways to achieve the same purpose?

Comment: Well... Just think about it... How can you exclude all the items of a still running Stream when you don't even know what they are?

Comment: At the each trigger point, I think that they will have all the information until that point. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What about the next Stream component down the line which has already consumed that `supposed to be removed element` ?

Comment: that could happen. Maybe I should go with another approach.

Comment: Did we arrive at any solution for this ? As I am having the same problem in my spark app.

Comment: any solution guys ?